# Hibernate save with nextval

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

It's possible to execute a select when I try to save one entity? for sample I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  private String number; 

}
```

I my propertie number I wanna to execute a

```
select nextval('numberGenerator')
```

this numberGenerator will generate a sequence of number without gap, even if my insert fails he won't lost the sequence

Comment: Are you using oracle and an oracle sequence?

Comment: Are you attempting to implement a gapless numeric range for things such as invoice numbers where certain country auditing rules mandate there not be gaps or are you just trying to avoid this as not to consume a row ID when an insert fails?

Comment: This will not create gapless ids. And gapless ids are a very bad idea since they require strong concurrency constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `@SequenceGenrator` to use a sequence saved on the database side. Your sequence should create a new id by nextval.

```
 @Id
 @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "numberGenerator", name = "numberGenerator", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "numberGenerator")
 private Long id;
```

Comment: in this case If my save fail he lost the sequence.

Comment: @FabioEbner are you sure this will happen?

Comment: @Patrick It can.  Imagine for a moment where the persist is about to occur.  Hibernate asks the sequence generator for the next value, the sequence at this point gets incremented by 1.  The insert statement then happens but a field that shouldn't be null is; the insert fails and transaction rolls back.  At this point that `NEXTVAL` sequence is lost because the database generates those in an atomic increment block to guarantee it does not give out the same sequence to multiple transactions simultaneously.

Comment: @Naros thanks for your explanation. I will not delete my answer because your explanation could be helpful for me and others.